# Pac4j and primefaces "p:fileUpload" not working

Tags: primefaces, pac4j

I´m trying to use Pac4j and Primefaces.

Unfortunately the p:fileUpload seems not working with this combination.

The issue is:
The backend function is never called:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <p:fileUpload listener="#{testBeanController.handleFileUploadPicture}"
            sizeLimit="2000000"  />
    </h:form>
```

My Bean:

```
public void handleFileUploadPicture(FileUploadEvent event)  {

        LOGGER.info("START handleFileUploadPicture");

        LOGGER.error("START handleFileUploadPicture");


        LOGGER.info("END handleFileUploadPicture");
    }
```

I´ve uploaded a testproject here:
https://file.io/DqDayoqO8TrT

Is there maybe anything to add in the web.xml ?